# Why does Hibernate try to delete associated object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a many-to-one relation between these two tables:

bankaccount (has a currency)
currency

When I delete a bankaccount hibernate tries to delete the currency from the currency table. That obviously does not make sense. My relations are as:

BankAccount:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_account")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BankAccount {
    //...other fields ommited
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "currency_id", nullable = true)
    private Currency currency;
    //...
}
```

Currency:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "currency")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(min = 2, max = 3)
    @NotNull
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "is_default")
    private boolean isDefault;

    //...ommited
}
```

When I use delete with BankAccount hibernate tries to delete the accompanied currency, which it cannot as other tables are referencing them obviously.

I have a very rusty knowledge of Hibernate, whats wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: No, it won't do that all by itself unless you have a cascade on the ManyToOne. If you don't, then your code does that somehow.

Comment: Think you need a onetomany annotation in your currency class, with a mappedBy and a cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: Eclipse cache or some form of cache caused the error. After restarting Eclipse AND my PC it worked...Only 1 hour wasted.